# C# exe file gets locked after open an explorer window and I get "error CS0016: Could not write to output file"

Tags: c#, csc

If I open an explorer window in the directory i.e. `start .` then as soon as I do that, I can't compile it and even after I close the explorer window, I can't compile it or delete the exe file for a while either.

```
C:\blah\ff>notepad.exe asdf.csc

C:\blah\ff>type asdf.csc
class a {  public static void Main(string[] args){} }
C:\blah\ff>
C:\blah\ff>csc asdf.csc
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest v
ersion. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240


C:\blah\ff>csc asdf.csc
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest v
ersion. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240


C:\blah\ff>csc asdf.csc
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest v
ersion. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
```

^^ no issues compiling there, now watch what happens when I do `start .`

```
C:\blah\ff>start .

C:\blah\ff>csc asdf.csc
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest v
ersion. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\blah\ff\asdf.exe' -- 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
        '

C:\blah\ff>csc asdf.csc
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest v
ersion. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\blah\ff\asdf.exe' -- 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
        '

C:\blah\ff>
```

After a while I can compile, and I can delete the exe file.

Now i'll demonstrate again, this time showing the issue deleting the exe file

See i'm able to compile ('cos I waited a while and I think that "resolved" it)

```
C:\blah\ff>csc asdf.csc
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest v
ersion. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
```

Now i'll trigger the issue

```
C:\blah\ff>start .

C:\blah\ff>csc asdf.csc
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest v
ersion. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\blah\ff\asdf.exe' -- 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
        '
```

^^ as you see it didn't compile

```
C:\blah\ff>del asdf.exe

C:\blah\ff>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\blah\ff

16/10/2016  03:13 AM    <DIR>          .
16/10/2016  03:13 AM    <DIR>          ..
16/10/2016  03:10 AM                53 asdf.csc
16/10/2016  03:13 AM             3,584 asdf.exe
               2 File(s)          3,637 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,886,389,760 bytes free
```

^^ look the exe file is still there
let's try to delete it again

```
C:\blah\ff>del asdf.exe
C:\blah\ff\asdf.exe
Access is denied.

C:\blah\ff>
```

So while i'm waiting for it to let me delete it or let me compile an exe of the same name, I use `csc /out:asdf_.exe asdf.csc` which is ok but not ideal.

Comment: You may also want to check what process holds the file open but I bet it will be explorer.exe... Likely you have some wired/buggy plugin installed that locks exe files when explorer window opens... Check for recently installed tools/viruses/antiviruses to see if you can spot it...

Comment: By any chance, do you have any explorer extensions that are perhaps taking a while to process the files it scans? Maybe even holding it open indefinitely? By doing `start .`, you're having the system start the default program for `.` which refers to the folder, which is `explorer`. Do you get the same behavior if you were to open an explorer window from the start/run menu to the folder and immediately try to compile?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you're right that I have something locking exe files when explorer windows open! I've absolutely no clue what it is

Comment: @JeffMercado  when I go to the run dialog box and open the explorer window from there then I still get the phenomenon.  It reminds me a little bit of that feature where you can't delete executables from system32 and they reappear if you try..  for files that are not EXE I do not have the issue!

Comment: I remember a similar question where it turned out that the target directory was in a dropbox sub-folder...

Comment: @helb not dropbox, and the process locking it shown by sysinternals process explorer, is system (PID 4), so no idea.

Comment: Wow, thats weird. You should include that in your question and also specify which version of Windows you are using and if you work in a virtualized environment.

Comment: @helb  I would though at the time of writing the question I thought csc was locking it so I posted on here.. Then I saw that it's not it's maybe explorer  or something else that locks it even after an explorer window is closed .. and it can happen even without csc.exe  so I figured it's more of a superuser question.. but i've never really seen an answer regarding how to determine what is locking a file  when all process explorer can show is system pid4.